# How to make \animategraphics options as a single batch parameter?

Tags: animate

I have a bunch of multi-page PDF files to be animated in various formats such as GIF, animated PDF, MP4, and animated SVG. To do so I write a batch file for each type of animations to animate those multi-page PDF files.

Only for the sake of simplicity, the code to produce a multi-page PDF is intentionally put into the animation-specific batch. In my real scenario, each batch only has code to produce a specific type of animation from a multi-page PDF.

The test input file to produce a multi-page PDF is given as follows:

```
% test.tex
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\begin{document}
\multido{\i=40+40}{9}
{
    \begin{pspicture}[showgrid=false](-2,-2)(2,2)
    \psline(2;\i)      
    \end{pspicture}
}
\end{document}
```

Each animating batch needs a wrapper that I actually put in my local TeX directory. The wrapper is as simple as follows.

```
% wrapper.tex
\documentclass[border=\Border]{standalone}
\usepackage[dvisvgm]{animate}
\usepackage[dvisvgm]{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\animategraphics[\Options]{\FrameRate}{\FileName}{}{}%
\end{document}
```

And the animating batch is as follows.

```
rem animator.bat
echo off

rem %1 input filename without extension
rem %2 frame rate
rem %3 animate options such as palindrome, controls, autoplay, scale=1, loop, etc
rem %4 standalone border

rem pre-cleaning
for %%x in (aux log dvi ps pdf svg) do (if exist "%~1.%%x" del "%~1.%%x")

latex "%~1.tex"
dvips "%~1.dvi"
ps2pdf "%~1.ps"

latex  --jobname="%~1" "\def\FileName{%~1}\def\FrameRate{%2}\def\Options{%~3}\def\Border{%4}\input{wrapper}"

dvisvgm --bbox=papersize --font-format=woff --zoom=-1 "%~1" 

rem post-cleaning
for %%x in (aux log dvi ps) do (if exist "%~1.%%x" del "%~1.%%x")
```

## Problem

Only for simplicity I put all of those files in a single directory. I invoke the batch from command prompt as follows

```
animator.bat test 10 "controls,scale=1,loop,autoplay,palindrome" 12pt
```

but I got the following errors.

> LaTeX Warning: Reference `anim@abspage0' on page 1 undefined on input
> line 5.
>
> ! Package xkeyval Error: `controls,scale=1,loop,autoplay,palindrome' undefined  in families` anim@user'.
>
> See the xkeyval package documentation for explanation. Type  H
>   for immediate help.  ...
>
> l.5 ...aphics[\Options]{\FrameRate}{\FileName}{}{}
> % ?

How to fix this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try `\expandafter\animategraphics\expandafter[\Options]{\FrameRate}{\FileName}{}{}%`

Comment: Out of topic: I found another problem when using `--precision=x` where `x<6` as mentioned in  my post [here](https://github.com/mgieseki/dvisvgm/issues/136).

Comment: Sorry. I meant `x<4`.